# How to query a publish without any books containing a specific topic? XML/Xquery

Tags: xml, xquery

How would i go as to query for a publisher who hasn't published any books about a specific topic?

I have 25 books written, and when i run this (which I thought would work)

```
/books/book[not(./topic="databases")]/publisher
```

It returned every single publisher.  There should be at-least 4 books on databases with 2 different publishers, however they also get returned on the query.

So how would i query this? The publishers who shouldn't query probably do that cause they have more books that are not on the queried topic.

Edit the xml i query:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?oxygen RNGSchema="compact_oblig3.rnc" type="compact"?>

<bøker>
    <bok isbn="1111">
        <tittle>Objects first with java</tittle>
        <utgave>6</utgave>
        <forfatter>David J. Barnes</forfatter>
        <utgivelsesår>2016</utgivelsesår>
        <fagfelt>Programmering</fagfelt>
        <fagfelt>Databaser</fagfelt>
        <innholdsfortegnelse> 
            <komponent>En komponent</komponent>
        </innholdsfortegnelse>
        <forlag>Pearson Education<url>http://www.pearsoned.co.uk/</url>
            <kontaktinfo>
                <telefon>08456301111</telefon>
                <epost>customersolutions@pearson.com</epost>
            </kontaktinfo>
        </forlag>
    </bok>

    <bok isbn="9780321197849">
        <tittle>An Introduction to Database Systems</tittle>
        <utgave>8</utgave>
        <forfatter>C.J.Date</forfatter>
        <utgivelsesår>2004</utgivelsesår>
        <fagfelt>Databaser</fagfelt>
        <innholdsfortegnelse>
            <komponent> Continuing in the eighth edition, An Introduction to Database Systems
                provides a comprehensive introduction to the now very large field of database
                systems by providing a solid grounding in the foundations of database technology
                while shedding some light on how the field is likely to develop in the future. This
                new edition has been rewritten and expanded to stay current with database system
                trends. </komponent>
        </innholdsfortegnelse>
        <forlag>Pearson Education<url>https://www.pearsonhighered.com/program/Date-An-Introduction-to-Database-Systems-8th-Edition/PGM274345.html</url>
        </forlag>
    </bok>

    <bok isbn="9788215015224">
        <tittle>Databasesystemer</tittle>
        <utgave>2</utgave>
        <forfatter>Bjørn Kristoffersen</forfatter>
        <utgivelsesår>2009</utgivelsesår>
        <fagfelt>Databaser</fagfelt>
        <innholdsfortegnelse>
            <komponent/>
        </innholdsfortegnelse>
        <forlag>Universitetsforlaget<url>http://www.bokkilden.no/SamboWeb/produkt.do?produktId=4136282</url>
            <kontaktinfo>
                <telefon>24147500</telefon>
                <epost>post@universitetsforlaget.no</epost>
                <adresse>
                    <gate>Sehesteds gate</gate>
                    <gatenmr>3</gatenmr>
                    <postnmr>0164</postnmr>
                </adresse>
            </kontaktinfo>
        </forlag>
    </bok>

    <bok isbn="032141506">
        <tittle>Fundamentals of Database Systems</tittle>
        <utgave>5</utgave>
        <forfatter>Elmasri</forfatter>
        <forfatter>Navathe</forfatter>
        <utgivelsesår>2007</utgivelsesår>
        <fagfelt>Databaser</fagfelt>
        <innholdsfortegnelse>
            <komponent/>
        </innholdsfortegnelse>
        <forlag>Pearson Education<url>https://www.pearsonhighered.com/product/Elmasri-Fundamentals-of-Database-Systems-5th-Edition/9780321369574.html</url>
        </forlag>
    </bok>

    <bok isbn="9780195138573">
        <tittle>Mindware</tittle>
        <forfatter>Andy Clark</forfatter>
        <utgivelsesår>2001</utgivelsesår>
        <fagfelt>Filosofi</fagfelt>
        <fagfelt>Kognitiv vitenskap</fagfelt>
        <innholdsfortegnelse>
            <komponent> Mindware: An Introduction to the Philosophy of Cognitive Science invites
                readers to join in up-to-the-minute conceptual discussions of the fundamental
                issues, problems, and opportunities in cognitive science. Written by one of the most
                renowned scholars in the field, this vivid and engaging introductory text relates
                the story of the search for a cognitive scientific understanding of mind. This
                search is presented as a no-holds-barred journey from early work in artificial
                intelligence, through connectionist (artificial neural network) counter-visions, and
                on to neuroscience, artificial life, dynamics, and robotics. The journey ends with
                some wide-ranging and provocative speculation about the complex coadaptive dance
                between mind, culture, and technology. Each chapter opens with a brief sketch of a
                major research tradition or perspective, followed by short yet substantial critical
                discussions dealing with key topics and problems. Ranging across both standard
                philosophical territory and the landscape of cutting-edge cognitive science, Clark
                highlights challenging issues in an effort to engage readers in active debate.
                Topics covered include mental causation; machine intelligence; the nature and status
                of folk psychology; the hardware/software distinction; emergence; relations between
                life and mind; the nature of perception, cognition, and action; and the continuity
                (or otherwise) of high-level human intelligence with other forms of adaptive
                response. Numerous illustrations, text boxes, and extensive suggestions for further
                reading enhance the text's utility. Helpful appendices provide background
                information on dualism, behaviorism, identity theory, consciousness, and more. An
                exceptional text for introductory and more advanced courses in cognitive science and
                the philosophy of mind, Mindware is also essential reading for anyone interested in
                these fascinating and ever-changing fields. </komponent>
        </innholdsfortegnelse>
        <forlag>Oxford University Press<url>https://global.oup.com/academic/</url>
            <kontaktinfo>
                <telefon>4401865556767</telefon>
                <epost>onlinequeries.uk@oup.com</epost>
            </kontaktinfo>
        </forlag>
    </bok>

    <bok isbn="9780631229193">
        <tittle>Philosophy of computing and information</tittle>
        <redaktør>Luciano Floridi</redaktør>
        <utgivelsesår>2004</utgivelsesår>
        <fagfelt>Filosofi</fagfelt>
        <fagfelt>Kunnskapsrepresentasjon</fagfelt>
        <fagfelt>Kunstig Intelligens</fagfelt>
        <fagfelt>Programmering</fagfelt>
        <innholdsfortegnelse>
            <komponent/>
        </innholdsfortegnelse>
        <forlag>Wiley<url>http://www.wiley.com/WileyCDA/WileyTitle/productCd-0631229191.html</url>
            <kontaktinfo>
                <telefon>4962016060</telefon>
                <epost>info@wiley-vch.de</epost>
                <adresse>
                    <gate>Boschstrasse</gate>
                    <gatenmr>12</gatenmr>
                    <postnmr>69469</postnmr>
                </adresse>
            </kontaktinfo>
        </forlag>
    </bok>          

    <bok isbn="9780631218685">
        <tittle>Philosophy of Logic</tittle>
        <forfatter>Jacquette Dale</forfatter>
        <utgivelsesår>2002</utgivelsesår>
        <fagfelt>Filosofi</fagfelt>
        <fagfelt>Logikk</fagfelt>
        <innholdsfortegnelse>
            <komponent/>
        </innholdsfortegnelse>
        <forlag>Wiley<url>http://www.wiley.com/WileyCDA/WileyTitle/productCd-0631218688.html</url>
            <kontaktinfo>
                <telefon>4962016060</telefon>
                <epost>info@wiley-vch.de</epost>
                <adresse>
                    <gate>Boschstrasse</gate>
                    <gatenmr>12</gatenmr>
                    <postnmr>69469</postnmr>
                </adresse>
            </kontaktinfo>
        </forlag>
    </bok>

    <bok isbn="9780198752530">
        <tittle>A Survey of Metaphysics</tittle>
        <forfatter>E.J.Lowe</forfatter>
        <utgivelsesår>2002</utgivelsesår>
        <fagfelt>Filosofi</fagfelt>
        <innholdsfortegnelse>
            <komponent/>
        </innholdsfortegnelse>
        <forlag>Oxford University Press<url>https://global.oup.com/academic/</url>
            <kontaktinfo>
                <telefon>4401865556767</telefon>
                <epost>onlinequeries.uk@oup.com</epost>
            </kontaktinfo>
        </forlag>
    </bok>

    <bok isbn="9780262024754">
        <tittle>Knowledge and Mind: A Philosophical Introduction</tittle>
        <utgave>1</utgave>
        <forfatter>Robert. J. Stainton</forfatter>
        <forfatter>Andrew Brook</forfatter>
        <utgivelsesår>2000</utgivelsesår>
        <fagfelt>Filosofi</fagfelt>
        <innholdsfortegnelse>
            <komponent/>
        </innholdsfortegnelse>
        <forlag>A Bradford Book<url>https://mitpress.mit.edu/category/imprint/bradford-book</url>
        </forlag>
    </bok>


    <bok isbn="9781412925686">
        <tittle>Cognitive Science</tittle>
        <utgave>1</utgave>
        <forfatter>Jay Friedenberg</forfatter>
        <forfatter>Gordon Silverman</forfatter>
        <utgivelsesår>2006</utgivelsesår>
        <fagfelt>Kognitiv vitenskap</fagfelt>
        <innholdsfortegnelse>
            <komponent/>
        </innholdsfortegnelse>
        <forlag>Sage Publications, Inc<url>https://uk.sagepub.com/en-gb/eur</url>
            <kontaktinfo>
                <telefon>4402073248500</telefon>
                <epost>market@sagepub.co.uk</epost>
            </kontaktinfo>
        </forlag>
    </bok>


    <bok isbn="9780262122320">
        <tittle>The logic of knowledge bases </tittle>
        <utgave>1</utgave>
        <forfatter>GerhaldLakemeyer</forfatter>
        <forfatter>Hector Levesque</forfatter>
        <utgivelsesår>2000</utgivelsesår>
        <fagfelt>Kunnskapsrepresentasjon</fagfelt>
        <fagfelt>Logikk</fagfelt>
        <innholdsfortegnelse>
            <komponent/>
        </innholdsfortegnelse>
        <forlag>The MIT Press<url>https://mitpress.mit.edu/</url>
        </forlag>
    </bok>

    <bok isbn="9781558609327">
        <tittle>Knowledge Representation and Reasoning</tittle>
        <utgave>1</utgave>
        <forfatter>Ronald Brachman</forfatter>
        <forfatter>Hector Levesque</forfatter>
        <utgivelsesår>2004</utgivelsesår>
        <fagfelt>Kunnskapsrepresentasjon</fagfelt>
        <innholdsfortegnelse>
            <komponent/>
        </innholdsfortegnelse>
        <forlag>Morgan Kaufmann<url>http://store.elsevier.com/product.jsp?isbn=9781558609327</url>
        </forlag>
    </bok>

    <bok isbn="9780521150118">
        <tittle>The description logic handbook </tittle>
        <utgave>2</utgave>
        <redaktør>Daniele Nardi</redaktør>
        <redaktør>Franz Baader</redaktør>
        <redaktør>Diego Calvanese</redaktør>
        <utgivelsesår>2007</utgivelsesår>
        <fagfelt>Kunnskapsrepresentasjon</fagfelt>
        <fagfelt>Logikk</fagfelt>
        <innholdsfortegnelse>
            <komponent/>
        </innholdsfortegnelse>
        <forlag>Cambridge University Press<url>http://www.cambridge.org/</url>
            <kontaktinfo>
                <telefon>4401223358331</telefon>
                <epost>information@cambridge.org</epost>
            </kontaktinfo>
        </forlag>
    </bok>

    <bok isbn="9780444522115">
        <tittle>Handbook of Knowledge Representation</tittle>
        <utgave>1</utgave>
        <redaktør>Frank von Harmelen</redaktør>
        <redaktør>Vladimir Lifschitz</redaktør>
        <redaktør>Bruce Porter</redaktør>
        <utgivelsesår>2008</utgivelsesår>
        <fagfelt>Kunnskapsrepresentasjon</fagfelt>
        <innholdsfortegnelse>
            <komponent/>
        </innholdsfortegnelse>
        <forlag>Elsevier Science<url>http://store.elsevier.com/product.jsp?isbn=9780444522115</url>
        </forlag>
    </bok>

    <bok isbn="9780201403756">
        <tittle>Prolog Programming for Artificial Intelligence</tittle>
        <utgave>3</utgave>
        <forfatter>Ivan Bratko</forfatter>
        <utgivelsesår>2001</utgivelsesår>
        <fagfelt>Kunstig Intelligens</fagfelt>
        <fagfelt>Programmering</fagfelt>
        <innholdsfortegnelse>
            <komponent/>
        </innholdsfortegnelse>
        <forlag>Pearson Education<url>https://www.pearsonhighered.com/</url>
        </forlag>
    </bok>


    <bok isbn="9780470035610">
        <tittle>Computational Intelligence </tittle>
        <utgave>2</utgave>
        <forfatter>Andries P. Engelbrecht</forfatter>
        <utgivelsesår>2007</utgivelsesår>
        <fagfelt>Kunstig Intelligens</fagfelt>
        <innholdsfortegnelse>
            <komponent/>
        </innholdsfortegnelse>
        <forlag>Wiley<url>http://www.wiley.com/WileyCDA/</url>
            <kontaktinfo>
                <telefon>4962016060</telefon>
                <epost>info@wiley-vch.de</epost>
                <adresse>
                    <gate>Boschstrasse</gate>
                    <gatenmr>12</gatenmr>
                    <postnmr>69469</postnmr>
                </adresse>
            </kontaktinfo>
        </forlag>
    </bok>



    <bok isbn="9780137903955">
        <tittle> Artificial Intelligence - a modern approach </tittle>
        <utgave>2</utgave>
        <forfatter>Stuart Russell</forfatter>
        <forfatter>Peter Norvig</forfatter>
        <utgivelsesår>2003</utgivelsesår>
        <fagfelt>Kunstig Intelligens</fagfelt>
        <innholdsfortegnelse>
            <komponent/>
        </innholdsfortegnelse>
        <forlag>Pearson education<url>https://www.pearsonhighered.com/product/Russell-Artificial-Intelligence-A-Modern-Approach-2nd-Edition/9780137903955.html</url>
        </forlag>
    </bok>


    <bok isbn="9780763718435">
        <tittle>Discrete structures, logic and computability </tittle>
        <utgave>2</utgave>
        <forfatter>James L. Hein</forfatter>
        <utgivelsesår>2002</utgivelsesår>
        <fagfelt>Logikk</fagfelt>
        <fagfelt>Matematikk</fagfelt>
        <innholdsfortegnelse>
            <komponent/>
        </innholdsfortegnelse>
        <forlag>Jones and Bartlett Learning<url>http://www.jblearning.com/</url>
            <kontaktinfo>
                <telefon>8008320034</telefon>
            </kontaktinfo>
        </forlag>
    </bok>


    <bok isbn="9780521708777">
        <tittle>The mathematics of logic</tittle>
        <utgave>1</utgave>
        <forfatter>Richard W. Kaye</forfatter>
        <utgivelsesår>2007</utgivelsesår>
        <fagfelt>Logikk</fagfelt>
        <fagfelt>Matematikk</fagfelt>
        <innholdsfortegnelse>
            <komponent/>
        </innholdsfortegnelse>
        <forlag>Cambridge University Press<url>http://www.cambridge.org/ </url>
            <kontaktinfo>
                <telefon>4401223358331</telefon>
                <epost>information@cambridge.org</epost>
            </kontaktinfo>
        </forlag>
    </bok>


    <bok isbn="9780521365840">
        <tittle>Lattices and order </tittle>
        <utgave>1</utgave>
        <forfatter>B. A. Davey</forfatter>
        <forfatter>H. A. Priestley</forfatter>
        <utgivelsesår>1990</utgivelsesår>
        <fagfelt>Matematikk</fagfelt>
        <innholdsfortegnelse>
            <komponent/>
        </innholdsfortegnelse>
        <forlag>Cambridge University Press<url>http://www.cambridge.org/</url>
            <kontaktinfo>
                <telefon>4401223358331</telefon>
                <epost>information@cambridge.org</epost>
            </kontaktinfo>
        </forlag>
    </bok>


    <bok isbn="9780201730470">
        <tittle>Discrete Mathematics for Computing</tittle>
        <utgave>1</utgave>
        <forfatter>Rod Haggarty</forfatter>
        <utgivelsesår>2001</utgivelsesår>
        <fagfelt>Matematikk</fagfelt>
        <innholdsfortegnelse>
            <komponent/>
        </innholdsfortegnelse>
        <forlag>Pearson education<url>https://www.pearsonhighered.com/</url>
        </forlag>
    </bok>

    <bok isbn="978-0521478175">
        <tittle>Conceptual Mathematics: A First Introduction to Categories</tittle>
        <utgave>1</utgave>
        <forfatter>F. William Lawvere </forfatter>
        <forfatter>Stephen Hoel Schanuel</forfatter>
        <utgivelsesår>1997</utgivelsesår>
        <fagfelt>Matematikk</fagfelt>
        <innholdsfortegnelse>
            <komponent/>
        </innholdsfortegnelse>
        <forlag>ELSEVIER<url>https://www.elsevier.com/</url>
        </forlag>
    </bok>


    <bok isbn="9780321392794">
        <tittle>Data Structures in Java</tittle>
        <utgave>1</utgave>
        <forfatter>Simon Gray</forfatter>
        <utgivelsesår>2007</utgivelsesår>
        <fagfelt>Programmering</fagfelt>
        <innholdsfortegnelse>
            <komponent/>
        </innholdsfortegnelse>
        <forlag>Pearson education<url>https://www.pearsonhighered.com/</url>
        </forlag>
    </bok>

    <bok isbn="978-0131374690">
        <tittle>Java software solutions</tittle>
        <utgave>3</utgave>
        <forfatter>John Lewis</forfatter>
        <forfatter>William Loftus</forfatter>
        <forfatter>Cara Cocking</forfatter>
        <utgivelsesår>2003</utgivelsesår>
        <fagfelt>Programmering</fagfelt>
        <innholdsfortegnelse>
            <komponent/>
        </innholdsfortegnelse>
        <forlag>Pearson education<url>https://www.pearsonhighered.com/</url>
        </forlag>
    </bok>

    <bok isbn="9780262012423">
        <tittle>A Semantic Web Primer</tittle>
        <utgave>2</utgave>
        <forfatter>Grigoris Antoniou</forfatter>
        <forfatter>Frank van Harmelen</forfatter>
        <utgivelsesår>2004</utgivelsesår>
        <fagfelt>Web</fagfelt>
        <innholdsfortegnelse>
            <komponent/>
        </innholdsfortegnelse>
        <forlag>MIT Press<url>https://mitpress.mit.edu/books/semantic-web-primer</url>
        </forlag>
    </bok>

    <bok isbn="9780321269669">
        <tittle>An introduction to XML and techologies</tittle>
        <utgave>1</utgave>
        <forfatter>Anders Moller</forfatter>
        <forfatter>Michael Schwartzbach</forfatter>
        <utgivelsesår>2005</utgivelsesår>
        <fagfelt>XML</fagfelt>
        <fagfelt>Programmering</fagfelt>
        <fagfelt>Web</fagfelt>
        <innholdsfortegnelse>
            <komponent></komponent>
        </innholdsfortegnelse>
        <forlag>Pearson Education Cananda<url>http://www.pearsoncanada.ca/</url>
            <kontaktinfo>
                <telefon>18005673800</telefon>
                <epost>cs.canada@pearson.com</epost>
                <adresse>
                    <gate>Prince Andrew Place</gate>
                    <gatenmr>26</gatenmr>
                    <postnmr>416</postnmr>
                </adresse>
            </kontaktinfo>
        </forlag>
    </bok>

    <bok isbn="2222222">
        <tittle>Jeg er en bok om Xpath</tittle>
        <utgave>2</utgave>
        <forfatter>Thomas Petersson</forfatter>
        <utgivelsesår>2016</utgivelsesår>
        <fagfelt>XML</fagfelt>
        <innholdsfortegnelse>
            <komponent></komponent>
        </innholdsfortegnelse>
        <forlag> Mitt forlag <url>www.eksempelforlag.no</url>
        </forlag>
    </bok>

</bøker>
```

These are 2 of the books I have written down, one without the wanted topic and one with (fagfelt)

Comment: Please post example data together with the expected output and what you're currently getting returned, otherwise answering your question is just guessword based on unknown facts and results in lengthy discussions.

Comment: And a more general hint: have a look at the last section in [FAQ: tagging](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) considering the preferred question title format on Stack Exchange.

Comment: Added 2 of the many books to give an image of how it's written.  It's in norwegian though, tell me if you need a translation to any of the words

Comment: @Peebl seems your query correctly returned the one without topic : http://xpatheval.apphb.com/1143eNq7V

Comment: @har07 That one works yeah, cause there is no other books, say i changed the publisher of the first book to the same as the 2nd, it would still give me the 2nd publisher http://xpatheval.apphb.com/6cUOLZFNh

Answer (score 0):

Hej Peebl,

This works for me, using your sample XML above:

```
bøker/bok[not(fagfelt = 'Databaser')]/forlag
```

It's probably a good idea to normalise your text while comparing. I typically wrap string comparisons in normalize-space and upper-case, which means a little reordering of your query:

```
bøker/bok[not(
    fagfelt[normalize-space(upper-case(.)) = 'DATABASER']
)]/forlag
```

You could also consider doing this with a FLWOR clause, which is a little more pleasant to read:

```
for $bok in $my.test/bok
where not($bok[fagfelt[normalize-space(upper-case(.)) = 'DATABASER']])
return $bok/forlag
```

Comment: What is $my.test if I may ask? Also the first query doesn't work on the larger version of the xml,  as it still returns publishers that has released a book without databaser. (updated the question with full xml)